# Exercise: Prove the following improper integral goes to $\;0\;$ as $\;n\to \infty\;$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $\;f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m\;$ be a continuous function such
>   that $\;\vert f(x)-a \vert \le e^{-kx}\;$ as $\;x \to +\infty\;$ and
>   $\;\vert f(x)-b \vert \le e^{kx}\;$ as $\;x \to -\infty\;$(NOTE: $\;k \gt 0\;$ and $\;a\neq b\;$)
>
> Take $\;y_n \in \mathbb R\;$ an unbounded sequence, in the sense that
>   $\;y_n\to \infty\;$ as $\;n\to \infty\;$. If $\;f(x-y_n) \to b\;$ as
>   $\;y_n \to \infty\;$, prove: $\;\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\vert f(x-y_n)-b \vert}^2 \;dx \to 0\;$ as $\;n \to \infty\;$

**My Attempt:**

$\;\int_{0}^{\infty} {\vert f(x-y_n) -b \vert}^2\;dx\le \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{2k(x-y_n)} \;dx\to 0\;$ as $\;y_n \to \infty\;$

However I'm a bit unsure if the above is valid since I used the estimate when $\;x-y_n \to -\infty\;$. I would really appreciate if somebody could confirm the above thought or in case it's wrong, fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, are you asking if the function $x \mapsto f(x-y_n)-b$ is square integrable?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, exactly. Sorry for the bad writting. How should I edit it?

Comment: The answer just depends on $a,b$, if $a=b$ it is in $L^2$, otherwise it is not. I would guess this is not what the original question was asking.

Comment: @copper.hat no, $\;a \neq b\;$. Could you explain to me why is my thought wrong?

Comment: If $f(x) \approx a$ for large positive $x$ then for large $x$ we have $|f(x-y_n) - b| \approx |a-b|$. This cannot be integrable if $a \neq b$.

Comment: @copper.hat But if $\;x \in (0,+\infty)\;$ and $\;y_n \to \infty\;$ then $\;x-y_n \to -\infty\;$, right? Thus I can use the estimate $\;\vert f(x)-b \vert \le e^{kx}\;$ substituting $\;x\;$ with $\;x-y_n\;$

Comment: The function mentioned in my first comment is a function of $x$ in which the $y_n$ is fixed. You need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm really sorry for the confusion here. I edited once more. Hope it's more clear now. I don't know which should be the appropriate title here for my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $n$, choose $K$ such that for $x \ge K$, $|f(x)-a| \le {1 \over 2} |a-b|$.

Then, if $x \ge K+y_n$, we have $|f(x-y_n)-a| \le {1 \over 2} |a-b|$.

Hence $|f(x-y_n) -b| \ge |a-b|-|f(x-y_n)-a| \ge {1 \over 2} |a-b| >0$.

In particular, the function $x \mapsto f(x-y_n) -b$ is not square integrable, and
we have $\lim_n \int_0^\infty |f(x-y_n) -b| dx = \infty$.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your time and your reply. However I see you didn't use the exponential estimates of $\;f\;$ at all... I still cannot see what I'm missing in my attempt and why I conclude to $\;0\;$ instead of $\;\infty\;$. I would be grateful if you could add more details..

Comment: I used the estimate when I choose $K$ above. I have no idea why you are using the second estimate for integrating on $[y_n,\infty)$.

Comment: ok.. I guess I've to check this from the start. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou: You don't need to accept this if it doesn't answer your question. The issue is that the integral must exist for a fixed $y_n$ first, before you can talk about limits.

Comment: If I had $\;\int_{-\infty}^{0} {\vert f(x-y_n) -b \vert}^2\;dx\;$ instead, then would this integral go to $\;0\;$ considering the above? I accepted the answer because you showed my initial assumption was wrong.

Comment: Yes, but that is a different question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73544/discussion-between-kaithkolesidou-and-copper-hat).